# Java - show information from database in JTextArea

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am working with MySQLWorkbench and Eclipse. In MySQLWorkbench I have a database, where I store my informations. Now I want to click on a button in my UI and want to get the informations in my JTextArea in Java. I tryed a lot but noting works. And the problem is that I don't know how I can access to the actionListener in the main class..

When I execute my code I can see it in the console but I want to show it in the TextArea..

That's the code I still have :

```
public static void main (String[] args) 

{

    //String x = txtfldVorname.getText();
     try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dblabor","root",""); 
           System.out.println("Connection successful");

                String sql = "SELECT name,nachname FROM kunden";
                ps= (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

                     rs = ps.executeQuery();

                     if(rs.next()){
                           String name = rs.getString("name");
                           String nachname = rs.getString("nachname");

                         System.out.print(" Nachname: " + name);
                         System.out.print(" Nachname: " + nachname);
                        }


                      rs.close();     

           /*System.out.println("Select kunden");
           st = con.createStatement();

           String sql = "SELECT * FROM kunden";
           rs= st.executeQuery(sql);

           String sql1 = "INSERT INTO kunden (name,nachname)"+ "VALUES(?,?)";
           PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql1);


           ps.execute();
           /*while(rs.next()) {

              String vorname= rs.getString("name");
              String nachname = rs.getString("nachname");


          System.out.format("%s,%s",vorname,nachname);
          }

          */
     } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println(e);
     }
}
 ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             buttonProf.addActionListener(al);


                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT name,nachname FROM kunden";
                    ps= (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                     rs = ps.executeQuery();

                     if(rs.next()){
                           String name = rs.getString("name");
                           String nachname = rs.getString("nachname");
                           textfeld.getText();

                         System.out.print("Name: " + name);
                         System.out.print(" Nachname: " + nachname);
                } 
                }//try
                catch (SQLException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }//catch

    }
```

.. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Assuming `textfeld` is your `JTextArea`, you could do something like `textfeld.append(name + "  " + nachname + "\n")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And where do I have to implement this?? Where in the line? @Berger

Comment: You may replace your `textfeld.getText();` statement with the above code.

Comment: Oh okey I will do that. But when I execute the code, the UI does not execute I just get the result in the console and when I execute the other class with the UI components and click on the button there is no action.. don't know how du combine these to classes.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setText()` method of the JTextArea to set the contents of the Text Area. 
You can checkout more about it from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)